# Could not find or load main class when a specific package is used

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar, kotlin

I need to use [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy).

My project can be run from IDE, but when I build it by gradle and add `compile 'net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.4'` into my gradle config file the jar is successfully built (there are no any errors), but the main function is not loaded:

`#gradle clean jar`

`#java -jar build/proxy-0.1.jar`

> "Error: Could not find or load main class myproject.MainKt"

If I add this utility to my existed package (that could be built and run as a fat jar) it can not be built.

What am I doing wrong?

Is it possible that it is bug in [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)?

Thanks.

My gradle file is the following:

```
group 'proxy'

version '0.1'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-gradle-plugin', version: kotlin_version
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version'
    compile 'net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.4'
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M6")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.0.0-M6")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0-M6")
}

jar {
    destinationDir = file('build/')
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'myproject.MainKt'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the way you execute the program. Or do you get the program somewhere else? If you get the error on building, please execute `./gradlew clear build --info --stacktrace` and post the output

Comment: Added running command. There are no errors on building.

Comment: Do you use any classes (in your main-class) of the `browsermob-core` library? If so, why don't you provide that library in the classpath when running?

Comment: It is proposed that fat jar will be built.